# Arduino clone changing its serial port on slight physical displacement, even during an ongoing serial communication

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication, clones

I'm using an Arduino clone for serial communication. However, as soon as I even touch the board, it resets, and the serial communication stops. When I view the serial port using the 'Tools' menu of Arduino IDE, I observe that it has changed. Sometimes, opening the serial monitor crashes Arduino IDE. I was using MATLAB as well, and observed that it crashed too whenever I initiated serial communication. The setup was working well for a week, when suddenly I encountered this problem. 
Do you think that there is a problem with Arduino clone? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a CH340G USB chip?

Comment: If the board is resetting when you touch it you might have a bad connection.  It could be worth checking you USB lead is plugged in properly, changing the USB cable and looking at the socket on the board for bad soldering.

Comment: Apologies for posting so late. I figured out that it was the problem with the board itself. As Matt suggested, it was bad soldering on the board. I replaced it with Arduino Uno, and it is working fine. Thanks.